# How to get list of selected rows during multiple selection in Qtableview?

Tags: c++, qt4

I have the data in Qtableview, where my task is, when ever I do multiple selection of rows I want the content of all selected rows. or at least I would like to know what are the row numbers I have selected.

For this I have written code which is giving 'Zero' every time even though I don't select any row.

```
ui->xvalue->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
ui->xvalue->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->xvalue->show();

QModelIndexList indexList =  ui->xvalue->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
int row;
foreach (QModelIndex index, indexList) {

row = index.row();
}
printf("\n%d\n",row);
```

I even tried this but no use I am not getting the answer

```
QItemSelectionModel* selectionModel = this-> ui->xvalue->selectionModel();

QModelIndexList selected = selectionModel->selectedIndexes();
int num;
for(int i= 0; i< selected.count();i++)
{
    QModelIndex index = selected.at(i);
    qDebug() << index.row();
    num = index.row();

    printf("selected row is %d", num); 
}
```

Comment: Put the printf() call before the right-curly-brace rather than after it.  (Right now you are printing only the last value that was assigned to row in the final iteration of the foreach loop; or if you didn't have any rows selected, then no value is ever assigned to the row variable and you are printing whatever uninitialized value that variable might happen to have)

Comment: I gave printf() before right curly braces , nothing is getting printed

Comment: If nothing gets printed it just means your selection is empty. When are you executing that code ? You need to do that whenever the selection changes with the signal `QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged`.